# ActionScript support for straw man skeleton in Open-NI NITE (Windows platform)

Tags: flash, actionscript, kinect, xbox, nui

I am interested in using XBox Kinect device on Windows (eventually with
Mac) machine together with Open NI/NITE.
I need to use advanced skeleton/straw man features of NITE.

I saw this exciting Kinect/Flash video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LKchGr9VIZE&feature=related

I finally installed Kinect drivers and Open NI components on my
Windows machine and played a bit with demos!
However, I cannot find good and straightforward way to interact with
Open NI / Kinect from Flash and access straw man functionality as you
do in this your videos!

1. Does anybody know if there is any "stable" windows service talking
   to native NITE that ActionScript client can talk with?
2. What components should I use to make Flash support with Open NI
   straw man features? Should I develop my own service that Flash
   connects to? Is there anything good published already? I saw only C#
   wrapper and I am not sure if it supports straw man features or only
   the basic features
3. Could anybody share at least the simplest code example with me?

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj131041.aspx) is pretty complicated so I don't recommend that a beginner should start with that, but I hope this leads you in the right direction.